# Find a vector in the plane spanned by two 4D vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let's say I have two vectors,
$$v_1 = (f(q),f(q),0,1)$$
$$v_2 = (f(q),f(q),1,0)$$
for some parameter $q$. For each $q$, these vectors span a plane. In particular there is a vector
$$v_0 = (0,0,-1,1)$$
which always lies in that plane. I would like to find the vector perpendicular to $v_0$ which lies in the plane (for all $q$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that adding $v_1$ and $v_2$ together produces the vector
$$
w
= \langle 2\,f(q), 2\,f(q), 1, 1\rangle
$$
and this vector lives in the plane of interest.

Dotting $w$ with $v_0$ gives
$$
w\cdot v_0
= \langle 2\,f(q), 2\,f(q), 1, 1\rangle\cdot \langle 0, 0, -1, 1\rangle
= 0
$$
Hence $w$ lives in the plane and is orthogonal to $v_0$.

*Side Note.* In this problem we're interested in finding certain vectors orthogonal to $v_0=\langle 0, 0, -1, 1\rangle$. Every vector orthogonal to $v_0$ is of the form $w=\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, -x_3\rangle$. So, the first two coordinates of $w$ can be chosen "freely" and the last two coordinates need to be related by negation. Looking at the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, we see that our $w$ can be created by adding.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice to spot something like that? I suppose that since I took the difference to get $v_0$ it would stand to reason trying the sum. But it seems these vectors are not orthogonal. I'm used to thinking in 3D, 4D vectors screw with me.

Comment: @Kai I added a "side note" that hopefully addresses your question.

Comment: Did you mean $f(q)$ where you wrote $f(1)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yep.